# I have problem loading all items from XML with for each

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm low level as3 programmer and I need help whit this code:

I have gallery XML file:

```
 <gallery>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <strana>0</strana>
        <naslov>Lokacije</naslov>
        <aktuelno>1</aktuelno>
        <slika>1.jpg</slika>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <strana>2</strana>
        <naslov>Coaching</naslov>
        <aktuelno>1</aktuelno>
        <slika>2.jpg</slika>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <strana>0</strana>
        <naslov><![CDATA[O.Å . Bratstvo - panel]]></naslov>
        <aktuelno>0</aktuelno>
        <slika>3.jpg</slika>
    </item>  
</gallery>
```

And:

var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest("gallery.xml");

```
var xml = new XML(evt.target.data);
for each(var item in xml..item) {
    centralniText.htmlText = item.slika;
}
```

only shows  last item from XML file:

```
3.jpg
```

I want all. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After storing your loaded xml data in an `XML` object:

```
var xml:XML = XML(URLLoader(event.target).data);
```

All you have to do is return an xml list value from the previous `XML` object's `children()` method:

```
var xmlList:XMLList = xml.children();
```

Then you can set it as your `TextField` object's `htmlText` property's value:

```
centralniText.htmlText = xmlList;
```

**[UPDATE]**

To access a specific element you can do the following:

```
trace(xmlList.slika[0]); // outputs: 1.jpg
trace(xmlList.slika[1]); // outputs: 2.jpg
trace(xmlList.slika[2]); // outputs: 3.jpg
```

Comment: Sorry can u explain me more, is this code used without for each loop?

Comment: Thank you. One more thing: how to access a specific child in an XMLList?

Comment: I want to use this for generating image URL's.

Comment: There are many ways to access specific child elements, I updated my answer to show what I thought was the most easiest.

Answer (score 1):

In your for each loop, you always assign the *current* item’s value to the text field, overwriting previous values. So you need to append the text, for example like this:

```
var text:String = '';
for each(var item in xml..item) {
    text += item.slika;
}
centralniText.htmlText = text;
```

Comment: It would be simpler to just use the returned `XMLList` value from `xml.children()`

Comment: When i use this code to load images this is result:

http://localhost/podaci/igraci/slike/1/1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg